# Table with images

Tags: tables

I want to make a table with 3 rows and 2 columns, where in the left column I put text and in the right column I put an image in each row.

I have no idea how to make this, I already tried to make a table, but I can't fix the column width, and I don't see the images (maybe the are outside the page?).

Could someone figure out how to do this?

This is what I mean, below. I want the text column to have more width than the picture column.

[image]

This is the code I have so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\newcommand\rowincludegraphics[2][]{\raisebox{-0.45\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{10cm}|p{10cm}}
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
       Text 1 & \rowincludegraphics[scale=0.4]{figure1.jpg} \\ \hline
       Text 2 & \rowincludegraphics[scale=0.4]{figure2.jpg} \\ \hline
       Text 3 & \rowincludegraphics[scale=0.4]{figure3.jpg} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The images now align to the top, but the text does not. How do I fix this? If this is fixed, the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Could we have a minimal (non)working example, illustrating the problem?

Comment: Like Bernard said, can you post the code you were working on including   `\documentclass{...} ... \begin{document} ... \end{document}`? Also, how big are the images?

Comment: Remember to *not* put the pictures inside a `figure` environment.

Comment: @Bernard, Alenanno I deleted my original code since it seemed to be a loose end.

Comment: you can see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238955/align-text-and-image-in-table

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Even non-working code saves people having to create a document from scratch and is therefore appreciated! (It avoids people having to type the boring bits like `\documentclass` before they can get to the interesting bit which is answering your question.)

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: @Mees that's still not a compilable code, it's missing `\documentclass`, the `document` environment, `\usepackage{array,graphicx}` and some definition of `\rowincludegraphics` which is not a standard macro AFAIK.

Comment: @Paul edited again. Can you now give the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file produces

```
 Overfull \hbox (233.45511pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--12
```

You have specified two columns of 10cm each which is much wider than the page.
Just let the columns be natural width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\newcommand\rowincludegraphics[2][]{\raisebox{-0.45\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
       Text 1 & \rowincludegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a} \\ \hline
       Text 2 & \rowincludegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-b} \\ \hline
       Text 3 & \rowincludegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That would work if in fact the text was literally 'Text 1', but the text is too long, so it needs to be broken off. Therefore there need be some kind of specified column width.

Comment: @Mees OK but only you know your text and only you know the size of images, so noone else can help you with that. You can of course change the first  `l`  back to `p{..}` but you need to pick something that is not wider than the page.

Comment: I picked \begin{tabular}{p{10cm},l}, and it's a bit less than my page width, but there still is this problem that my text is not aligned to the top.. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Mees Please don't ask new questions in comments, ask a new question as a new question, but also I can not guess what you mean so could not even guess an answer. Make a complete example document that shows the alignment problem, use the `example-image` as in my answer so people can run your example and see the problem, then ask a new question on the site.

Comment: It's on the bottom of my damn post! "The images now align to the top, but the text does not. How do I fix this? If this is fixed, the problem is solved. Thanks."

Comment: @Mees I can't really guess what you mean but you have vertically centred the images so the vertical centre aligns with the top of the text, perhaps you want to change -.45\height to -.9\height or -\dimexpr\height-\ht\strutbox\relax so the reference point is near the top of the image

Answer (score 1):

I would omit all vertical rules in the table, drop about half of the horizontal rules, and use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining horizontal lines.

And, do make sure that the `tabular` environment has a chance of fitting inside the text block. In the example below, I've chosen widths of 6cm and 7cm, respectively, for columns 1 and 2.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{7cm} % width of second column
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{6cm} p{\mylength} @{}}
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ 
    \midrule \addlinespace
    Text 1 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{figure1.jpg} 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Text 2 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{figure2.jpg} 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Text 3 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{figure3.jpg} 
    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```