# Problem with formatting Text in Table

Tags: tables, graphics, formatting, text

Here is my code. Every time I include an image into my table the text in the same row skip lines and start from the bottom, to align itself [the text] with the image. 
Can you please advise me on how to fix it? 
Thank you.

```
  \begin{document} 

    \begin{center} 
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    This is what I am talking about & How do I get it to start from the top?& \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img/smiley.jpg} \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238955/align-text-and-image-in-table?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is the image is laid on the base line, so you have to use `\raisebox{}`. The `cellspace` package defines a *minimal* vertical padding between the above and below rules, for columns with specifier prefixed by the letter `S`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, cellspace}
\renewcommand\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\renewcommand\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|Sc|} \hline
This is what I am talking about & How do I get it to start from the top?& \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1ex\relax}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{traccia-table}} \\[1ex] \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot to check the O.P.'s code. Thanks for pointing it.